# Adding Second Plugin Author

Tags: plugin-development

**Background:** I have a few plugins in the WordPress directory and have recently made the decision to team up with another individual to grow one plugin faster. I'm planning on adding him as a plugin author, but I want to be sure that if I do so there's no risk of me "losing control" of my plugin.

**Question:** If I add another author, is there any way that the new author can remove me as plugin author? Can they upload the plugin with their username and password, or am I still the only one that can upload changes?

I couldn't find anything on this topic, and I'd really hate to have my plugin stolen as I've become somewhat attached to it.

Comment: Ref: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/change-the-plugin-author-on-the-wordpress-plugin-directory#comment120099_88842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the author as contributor and all I know, he does not get automatically write access to your svn repository. You can also just mentioning the other author without adding him as contributor.

My personal opinion is, if you're worried that the other author steals your code, then he is the wrong helper.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not really worried he's going to steal it, just wanted to take precautions.